# How to paraphrase a wordy sentence

Tags: paraphrasing

I have the following sentence, but it looks word. How to get it concise and clear?

```
My friend John, a smart postgraduate, once worked on a project 
which was assigned by his professor and was required to finish in three months.
```

Comment: The easiest thing is to break it into more than one sentence.  "My friend John is..." "He once worked on a project..."

Comment: My friend John, a smart postgraduate, once worked on a project 
that his professor required in three months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My friend John, a smart postgraduate, once worked on a project 
>   which was assigned by his professor and was required to finish in three months.

A couple of suggested alternatives:

- John, my friend and a smart postgraduate, was assigned by a professor to work on a project with a completion time of three months.
- John, a smart postgraduate and friend, had a professor who assigned him to work on a project with a completion time of three months.